# PHP - Stripe IPN Using Webhooks Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to make an IPN through Stripe so the customer can pay via credit card.
I have added the javascript widget into my site as below:

```
<form id="stripe" action="ipn/stripe/stripe.php" method="POST">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="'.PK_TEST.'"
        data-amount="'.item_price.'"
        data-name="'.item_name.'"
        data-description="IPN Test"
        data-label="Pay with Stripe &raquo;"
        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-email="'.$email.'"
        data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>
```

It works correctly as on my stripe account, I can see the logs for the IPN page (`ipn/stripe/stripe.php`).

The issue is that the code I'm using in my IPN isn't getting passed through or an error is being executed stopping my mail from emailing me.

***This is my IPN code (Note that I changed the email and password so thats not the error, I just didn't want everyone seing my login):***

```
<?php
// Load the Stripe library
require_once 'init.php';
include('../../config/config.php');

// Set your LIVE or TEST secret key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_a8mZExfLGSxNXalX0W3RIXAq');

// Retrieve the request's body
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
if (!$body)
    return;

// Parse $body as JSON
$event_json = json_decode($body);
if (!$event_json)
    return;

// Quietly exit out if incomplete data
if ($event_json->object != 'event')
    return;

if (!isset($event_json->id))
    return;

$event_id = $event_json->id;

try {
    // Retrieve authentic event directly from Stripe
    $event = \Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);
    http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    $err_msg = 'Error: Stripe Webhook. Event id: ' . $event_id . '. ' . $e;
    // Additionally, send email if needed
    error_log($err_msg, 0);
}

// Match up each event type with a function and pass it the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'charge.failed':
        charge_failed($event);
        break;
        
    case 'charge.succeeded':
        charge_succeeded($event);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#                   Funtions for above                     #
# # # # # # ## # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 

function charge_failed($event) {
    // function code...
    $to = 'benzahdd55@outlook';
    $message = purchase_email('Error', '0.10', $to, '24-03-2018', 'ABC-ABC-ABC-ABC', 'Ben Wilson');
    require_once('../../mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    include("../../mailer/class.smtp.php"); 
    require '../../mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();    
    $body = $message;
    $subject = "Error";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing) || 1 = errors and messages || 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth  = true; // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host      = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Port      = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username  = "my_email@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password  = "password1"; // SMTP account password
    $mail->SetFrom("admin@easyipn.us", project_name." Admin");
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "Buyer@".project_name);

    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= "About to send mail\n";
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
    http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
}
function charge_succeeded($event) {
    // function code...
    $to = 'benzahdd55@outlook';
    $message = purchase_email('Success', '0.10', $to, '24-03-2018', 'ABC-ABC-ABC-ABC', 'Ben Wilson');
    require_once('../../mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    include("../../mailer/class.smtp.php"); 
    require '../../mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();    
    $body = $message;
    $subject = "Success!";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing) || 1 = errors and messages || 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth  = true; // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host      = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Port      = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username  = "my_email@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password  = "password1"; // SMTP account password
    $mail->SetFrom("admin@easyipn.us", project_name." Admin");
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "Buyer@".project_name);

    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= "About to send mail\n";
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
    http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
}


http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
?>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to send mail using PHPMailer upon a successfull payment.

When I use the Stripe 'Send a test event to a webhook endpoint', it shows me the response of : `
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe_Event' not found in /storage/ssd4/819/5144819/public_html/ipn/stripe/stripe.php:30
Stack trace:

## 0 {main}

thrown in **/storage/ssd4/819/5144819/public_html/ipn/stripe/stripe.php** on line **30**
saying that `Stripe_Event` isn't found.

I'm calling the init.php file which should be loading everything.
Am I calling stripe_event wrong or what ?

Comment: \Stripe\Stripe_Event?

Comment: @lollmbaowtfidgafgtfoohwtbs still getting this error : `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe\Stripe_Event' not found in /storage/ssd4/819/5144819/public_html/ipn/stripe/stripe.php:30
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>/storage/ssd4/819/5144819/public_html/ipn/stripe/stripe.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />`

Comment: your code seems to be missing the Strip_Event class. You said it worked somewhere else, but doesnt work in another place? Are you using this?: github.com/stripe/stripe-php/tree/master/lib If so, there is no Stripe_Event to use.

What are you trying to do exactly? Didnt you already retrieve the event data up above the Strip_Event code...a couple lines up?